# How can I vectorize a function made with Scipy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I created a function with Scipy to get the slope and r values. The idea is to select by "key", "Days", and "Fruit weights" and see how they increase on time. Here is an example of my raw data and code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MfpS.png)

## f(x)

```
def fx_stats(df,key):
    df = (df[df.key == key]).copy()   
    slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(df.Days, df.Calculated_fruit_weight_g)
    df.name = key
    df.dat = df.Datapoints[df.key == key].unique()[0]
    return df.name, slope, r_value, r_value**2, slope*7, df.dat
```

## Loop

```
results = []
key = d.key.unique()


for i in key:
        results.append(fx_stats(d,i))
results = pd.DataFrame(results)
fruits = results.rename(columns ={0:'key',1:'slope_g_per_day',2:'Pearson_r',3:"R2",4:'gain per week',5:'Datapoints'})
fruits
```

Question: How can I do this elegantly (short) way? I want to use Numpy vectorization to skip the loop, but I haven't been successful.

Expected result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7yzM.png)

Comment: Since you are working with a dataframe, and selecting "rows" by some value `key`, I doubt if you can translate this into some higher-dimension numpy array call.  But do you need to call  `stats.linregress` twice (for each key).  Aren't you doing the same thing each time, just collecting `slope` in one, and `r_value` in the other?  One call that returns both would be more efficient.

Comment: Legend! I add your suggestion, and my code has improved significantly!

Comment: What is `d`? This is not reproducible

Comment: Sorry "d" was my original dataset. I put a link to a screenshot at the beginning of the post.